# How to create named code blocks in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

When Intellij generates code for UI forms you can collapse the code block and it is named: "UI Designer generated code". It is possible to collapse a code selection but its collapsed representation is displayed as "...". Is it possible to give it a custom name? 
It would look similar to a collapsed #region code block in C#.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

They have implemented region-support now!

From http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80636

Currently Intellij IDEA supports two basic types of custom folding comments:

NetBeans-like:

```
//<editor-fold desc="...">
... code ...
//</editor-fold>
```

And VisualStudio-like:

```
//region <...>
... code ...
//endregion
```

Note that line commenting symbols for "region...endregion" can be changed from "//" to "#" if the '#' character is supported by a language. But by default custom folding comments use the same comment characters as normally used for language line comments.
Instead of typing the comments manually, in many cases you can use Ctrl+Alt+T (surround with).
Please submit separate issues if you find that something doesn't work as expected.

Comment: is there a way to automatically fold (on load) specific regions maybe using editor-fold desc property or something?

Comment: Also refer to [IntelliJ IDEA blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/03/custom-code-folding-regions-in-intellij-idea-111/).

Answer (score 15):

### There is a shortcut for that:

Open `Surround with` menu, by pressing

Linux/Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Mac: <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

And than choose `<editor-fold...> Comments` option

[image]

### Or you can do it manually.

For Java/Scala it is:

```
//<editor-fold desc="DESCRIPTION">
   ___YOUR_CODE___
//</editor-fold>
```

For Python it's almost the same

```
# <editor-fold desc="DESCRIPTION">
   ___YOUR_CODE___
# </editor-fold>
```

### Example:

```java
//<editor-fold desc="Main">
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
}
//</editor-fold>
```

Answer (score 6):

<s>IDEA [doesn't have such feature](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEABKL-4890) yet, please watch/vote the linked issue.</s>

**UPDATE**: this feature is available starting from IDEA 11.1 release.

Comment: How it then creates "UI Designer generated code" region? (I am using Intellij 10)

Comment: This is now implemented, so this answer should be deleted.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to replace `#` by `//` like below :

```
//region Description

 ... Your Code ...

//endregion
```