# Custom definition of "Group by methods defining type" in android studio / intellij

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, lint

In Android Studio, or Intellij, in the Structure View of a class the methods can be grouped by defining type ( for example, all methods of AppCompatActivity are in a sub-view ).

Can I create a custom definition to group up some generic methods ? And How ? 
Is there a lint annotation ?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-90273.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706661/how-to-create-named-code-blocks-in-intellij), use the `region-support`

```
//region Description
... Your Code ...
//endregion
```

to get something like this

[image]